# Python, Lists, Removing Rows

Tags: python, list

I have list of items (each row has the following: item number, lot number, description, total quantity). If a certain lot-number in my list exists twice, I add the quantities of both those rows together.  "data" is my original list. "max_item" is the max times an item occurs in "data". I created a new list (one_lot_per_row_list) and have appended my updated rows to it, but I also need to add the rows from "data" that did not have duplicate lots. Or I need to remove the row that was not updated from "data" (data[i+1+j]) in my code below. Not sure if the best way to approach this is to create a new list or to remove rows from my original. Hopefully this makes sense! All help very appreciated!

Example list below -- The final 2 rows have the same Internal Lot number. I would like to add their Total Available quantities together, and then remove the row that was not updated.

```
Part Internal Lot Number Description Total available Expiration Date Location

0001    QLN03867    P   2   3/31/2025   FRZ06 Half 1
0002    QLN03923    A   15  4/30/2023   F01-S01-05
0002    QLN03469    A   3   9/30/2022   F01-S03-02
0003    QLN03924    G   15  9/30/2022   F01-S01-05
0003    QLN03470    G   2   9/30/2022   F01-S01-02
0004    QLN03466    U   4   10/31/2022  F01-S03-02
0005    QLN03925    C   10  4/30/2023   F01-S01-02
0005    QLN03471    C   2   9/30/2022   F01-S01-02
0006    QLN03468    R   5   7/31/2021   F01-S03-02
0007    QLN03994    I   2   4/13/2025   F01-S03-03
0007    QLN03994    I   1   4/13/2025   F01-S03-02


data = []
for row in csv_reader:
     azpn = row[0]
     azln = row[1]
     description = row[2]
     location = row[5]
     date = datetime.strptime(row[4], '%m/%d/%Y')
     total_available = int(row[3])

     data.append([azpn, azln, description, total_available, date, location])

one_lot_per_row_list = []
i = 0
j = 1
for i in range(len(data)- max_item):
# if the lot number of row i is equal to the lot number of row i + j

    for j in range(max_item):
        if data[i][1] == data[i+1+j][1]:
             #add total available of data[i] to row data[i+1+j]
            data[i][3] += data[i+1+j][3]
            #append the new row to one_lot_per_row_list
            one_lot_per_row_list.append(data[i])
    j+=1
i+=1
```

Comment: Can you add the sample `input/output` list??

Comment: @9769953 does this have to do with where it is indented to? should the i+=1 be aligned with the original for loop?

Comment: @Nk03 - I edited the post... wass this what you were looking for?

Comment: Nope!!..  I'm looking for a sample `list of items`  that you've just top 10 elements will work and the expected output based on that `sample` list.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect, and the requirement is not clear

Comment: @9769953 no that isn't how for-loops work at all. Indeed, both `j += 1` and `i += 1` are pointless here, because they happen at the end of the for-block, and get immediately overwritten by the next value in the iterators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so I don't need them at all?

Comment: @codian *they do nothing useful* and frankly, make me suspect you don't really understand how your loops work

Comment: Anyway, you really need to provide a [mcve]. Your text isn't a csv....

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues edited the indentations ... also added some clarification. let me know if you better understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: No, the block after `for row in csv_reader:` is still unindented.

Answer (score 0):

You could pursue your approach or go for a more elegant method as follows:

1. Sort by lot number
2. Group by lot number
3. Use the reduce function to merge the items in each group.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do this very easily via `pandas`. The alternative is `itertools groupby`:

Here's one way via `pandas`:

1. `groupby` lot number and transform the column `Total`.
2. drop the duplicates based on `subset` = `['Internal Lot Number', 'Total']`
3. Finally, save the CSV file via `to_csv`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your csv file path here')
df.assign(Total=df.groupby('Internal Lot Number')['Total'].transform('sum')).drop_duplicates(
    ['Internal Lot Number', 'Total']).to_csv('output csv file path here')
```